# Range of int and float in C++

Tags: c++, floating-point, int

In C++ both [int](/questions/tagged/int) and [float](/questions/tagged/float) types take 4 bytes in memory (in my machine), then **how could float represent much larger number than int?**

```
#include <iostream>
#include<climits>
#include<cfloat>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    cout<<fixed;
    cout<<"Size of int: "<<sizeof(int)<<" bytes."<<endl;
    cout<<"Size of float "<<sizeof(float)<<" bytes."<<endl;
    cout<<"Int ranges from "<<INT_MIN<<" to "<<INT_MAX<<endl;
    cout<<"Float ranges from "<<FLT_MIN<<" to "<<FLT_MAX<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This program gives following output:

> Size of int: 4 bytes.
>
> Size of float 4 bytes.
>
> Int ranges from -2147483648 to 2147483647
>
> Float ranges from 0.000000 to 340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000

Clearly [float](/questions/tagged/float)'s max limit is much higher than that of [int](/questions/tagged/int).

Comment: *"In C++ both int and float types take 4 bytes in memory"* - On *your* machine. On someone else's int may be 8 bytes wide.

Comment: `int` represents all the integer numbers in it's range, while floating point only some.

Comment: As for the range. Who said they the bits in the 4 bytes must represent **the same thing**?

Comment: Check standard for floating point numbers

Comment: Have a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic

Comment: Nicely written question by the way, but there's probably a duplicate, and it's possibly too broad anyway. Vote to close, but please don't take that personally. Briefly, *every* `int` can be represented in the `int` range, but that is *not* true for the `float` range.

Comment: The short explanation is that a float can move the floating point location in order to represent large numbers, but it doesn't keep the accuracy of the lower digits. You should go to the wiki for more info.